# Unsubscribe and Update Profile not working, "javascript:void(0);"

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Having members state the marketing cloud emails profile and unsubscribe links are not working and pointing to the javascript void error. They are working for external members but not internal.

I receive a not secure warning in chrome next to the URL for the Subscription Center. What are the possible issues here? Help appreciated, thanks.

More details: The error occurs when a user clicks on the link in the email. Currently using the standard subscription and unsubscribe centers that are working fine for me and outside on gmail.

Comment: You need to provide more details. “javascript:void(0);” in itself is not an error. Are you using the standard subscription center? Are you referring to the link in the email itself? Or is the error within the preference center? I have more questions, but I can only ask you to be as detailed when addressing this community, describing exact details of your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the followup Lukas, the error occurs when a user clicks on the link in the email. Currently using the standard subscription and unsubscribe centers that are working fine for me and outside on gmail. Currently the issue is affecting internal members of @domain of which I am not a member.

Is this due to restrictions for links from external sources by the IT department for the company or are there other possibilites?

Comment: What kind of emails do you send to them - are those test emails or are they a part of an actual send?

Comment: I believe it's because the profile setting links from marketing cloud are not secure and are blocked internally by their IT settings. Setting up SSL is mandatory @zuzannamj ? SFMC is quoting 4-6 weeks to get that setup which seems excessive and a long roadblock to get things going.

Comment: It's not mandatory but it's the only way to go... and get 2x SSL, one for links and one for images etc. No other way around it and it's not possible to speed it up by getting the SSL yourself - we tried and failed miserably ;-)

Comment: You might be better off, waiting for the [self service SSLs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2020_setup_selfserve_ssl.htm&type=5) coming in the next release. This will hopefully speed things up

Comment: @zuzannamj Thanks, got the ball rolling now waiting for the SSL to finish on links and images. The self service feature looks promising, maybe next implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to IT spam filtering setup, very high threshold of not allowing nearly anything in, once the settings were adjusted: the MC IP addresses whitelisted for shared IP, sending domains added to threat level 0, the links were working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Subscription and Profile Center links are "system generated links", meaning they are only generated during a live email send. If you send a test version of the email internally, then the recipients will see "javascript:void(0);".

Are you seeing this on the test version or the live version?